# Memory leak in python code

Tags: python, memory-leaks, pytorch

I am trying to make my own dataset with torch in Python. However, the memory usage leaks in every file open.

The memory leak is occurred during the below for loop

```
for subj, _file in enumerate(filelist):
```

I deleted unnecessary in the code like import

```
parser.add_argument('--stddev', dest='stddev', default='subject', type=str, help="How to calculate ")
args = parser.parse_args()

# Options
if args.sess_num == 0:
  label_set = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

base_dir = './kriss_proto'
ori_base_dir = '{}/original'.format(base_dir)
filelist = os.listdir(ori_base_dir) # ['BD001.mat', ...]
filenum = len(filelist)

# Saving data
eeg_data = {}
eeg_data['dataset'] = {}
split_data = {}
split_data['splits'] = []
split_data['splits'].append({})

_meanstd = []
for i in range(32):
  _meanstd.append([])
  if args.stddev == 'subject':
    for j in range(filenum):
      _meanstd[i].append([])

idx = 0

for subj, _file in enumerate(filelist):
  filepath = os.path.join(ori_base_dir, _file)
  with h5py.File(filepath, 'r') as mat:

    ## Step by step (with object searching)
    bd_eeg = mat.get('BD_EEG')
    vst = bd_eeg.get('VST')

    for run in vst.keys():
      print("Processing {} - {}".format(_file, run))
      run_data = vst.get(run)
      eeg = run_data['data3D']
      eeg = th.Tensor(eeg)
      eeg = eeg.permute(2, 1, 0)

      label = run_data['class_labels']
      label = th.Tensor(label)
      label = th.squeeze(label)

      # DATA COPY
      for i in range(int(label.shape[0])):
        if (label[i] in label_set) and (int(eeg[i].shape[0]) > 400):
          eeg_data['dataset'][idx] = {}
          eeg_data['dataset'][idx]['eeg'] = eeg[i, :, :32]
          eeg_data['dataset'][idx]['label'] = label[i] - label_set[0] # label should start from 0
          if args.stddev == 'whole':
            for j in range(32):
              for k in range(int(eeg[i].shape[0])):
                _meanstd[j].append(eeg[i][k, j])
          elif args.stddev == 'subject':
            for j in range(32):
              for k in range(int(eeg[i].shape[0])):
                _meanstd[j][subj].append(eeg[i][k, j])     

          idx += 1
```

Comment: How do you know there is a memory leak?

Comment: It's normal behavior for the program to use more memory when you open files and store data in variables. Once you get out of the loop with the open file, does the memory go down again?

Comment: @cdark leaking is what I guess. Because, the original file size is about 3GB but when I read this data and make it into python list (include dictionary), the usage of mem is over 30GB. I know the size difference between file formats, but 10 times over is a non-sense.

Comment: @ChukUltima I goes down a little at the end of every file read. However, as I mentioned to cdarke, the memory usage looks weird at all.